# Как вернуть массив создаваемый методом .split из метода?

Tags: массивы, split, return

```
String regex = "[,\\.\\s+;]";

String[] splitter = text.split(regex);

return splitter[];
```

и вот как возвращать полученный массив не понимаю, или сама идея является некорректной?

Comment: `return text.split(regex);` не подходит?

Comment: Я там разобрался, проблема в методе была) возвращать надо было строку)